# ozeki NG fsockopen(): unable to connect to 197.XXX.XXX.XX:9501 (Connection timed out)

Tags: php, sms, smpp, fsockopen

i am working to send sms with ozeki NG and PHP, and i can send SMS from localhost but when i upload it on cpanel it says "fsockopen(): unable to connect to 197.XXX.XXX.XX:9501 (Connection timed out)"

IS THEIR ANY ONE WHO COULD HELP ME...thanks in advance...

```
$ozeki_user = "xxxx";
$ozeki_password = "xxxx";
$ozeki_url = "http://197.xxx.xxx.xxx:9501/api?";


function httpRequest($url){
$pattern = "/http...([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*).([0-9]*).(.*)/";
preg_match($pattern,$url,$args);
$in = "";
$fp = fsockopen("$args[1]", $args[2], $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
   return("$errstr ($errno)");
} else {
    $out = "GET /$args[3] HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $args[1]:$args[2]\r\n";
    $out .= "User-agent: Ozeki PHP client\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
       $in.=fgets($fp, 128);
    }
}
fclose($fp);
return($in);
}



function ozekiSend($phone, $msg, $debug=true){
  global $ozeki_user,$ozeki_password,$ozeki_url;

  $url = 'username='.$ozeki_user;
  $url.= '&password='.$ozeki_password;
  $url.= '&action=sendmessage';
  $url.= '&messagetype=SMS:TEXT:UCS2';
  $url.= '&recipient='.urlencode($phone);
  $url.= '&messagedata='.urlencode($msg); 
  //$url.= '&messagedata='.urlencode($msg);



  $urltouse =  $ozeki_url.$url;
  if ($debug) { echo "Request: <br>$urltouse<br><br>"; }

  //Open the URL to send the message
  $response = httpRequest($urltouse);
  if ($debug) {
       echo "Response: <br><pre>".
       str_replace(array("<",">"),array("&lt;","&gt;"),$response).
       "</pre><br>"; }

  return($response);
 }



$phonenum = $_POST['recipient'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$debug = true;

ozekiSend($phonenum,$message,$debug);

?>
```